# convert numeric variable into POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

i have a variable that contains values about 
*" the beginning of time interval expressed as the number of millisecond elapsed from the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC."* (according to data source metadata)

This is the head:

> x$timeInt
>       [1] 1.388068e+12 1.388075e+12 1.388096e+12 1.388051e+12 1.388051e+12 1.388072e+12

So i try to convert it as POSIXct

```
as.POSIXct(x$timeInt, origin = '01-01-1970',tz='UTC')
```

but i get this result

```
[1] "43987-03-01 05:20:00 UTC" "43987-05-23 13:20:00 UTC" "43988-01-28 13:20:00 UTC" "43986-08-25 17:20:00 UTC"
[5] "43986-08-25 17:20:00 UTC" "43987-04-25 18:40:00 UTC"
```

As you can see, the year is totally wrong. I tried using other formats in origin like  "1970-01-01", but the result is the same.
I know thata data is taken in december 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take care, that this is in milliseconds, so:

```
x$timeInt <- x$timeInt/1000
```

And then one of the two approaches:

```
as.POSIXct(x$timeInt, origin = '1970-01-01',tz='UTC')
```

or

```
library(anytime)

anytime(x$timeInt)

#[1] "2013-12-26 15:26:40 CET" "2013-12-26 17:23:20 CET" "2013-12-26 23:13:20 CET" "2013-12-26 10:43:20 CET" "2013-12-26 10:43:20 CET"
#[6] "2013-12-26 16:33:20 CET"
```

Comment: it doesn't work. with as.POSIXct(x = x$timeInt/1000, origin = '01-01-1970', tz='UTC') i get "45-01-13 14:20:00 UTC"

Comment: Change the origin value ... it is not the same as in my answer