# r programming to find time range by using simple way

Tags: r, date, time

```
#sample data
df.test <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,1,1,1),time=c("01:30:00","02:05:00","02:40:01","01:44:01","01:33:01","05:00:01"))

df.test $date.time <- as.POSIXct(df.test $time,format="%H:%M:%S")

#group the time per bour
df.test $date.hour <- cut(df.test $date.time, breaks="hour")
head(df.test)

#count how many people per hour
people.count <- df.test%>%group_by(date.hour)%>% summarize(count.user=n()) %>% arrange(count.user)
people.count

#find the smallest people and show the ralated hour
start.hour <- strptime(as.character(people.count$date.hour[1]),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#convert time to numeric
num.start.hour <- gsub("[: -]", "" ,start.hour, perl=TRUE)
num.end <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(start.hour))-1
#print(num.end)

#convert numeric to time
library(anytime)
anytime(num.end)

hr.range <- paste0(format(start.hour,"%H:%M:%S")," - ",format(num.end,"%H:%M:%S"))
hr.range
```

I am trying to find this dataset the smallest time range. This is my expected result. I watched several posts such as how to split the date and time formate [Split date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292438/split-date-time) and convert numeric of time [convert the numeric variable into POSIXct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817372/convert-numeric-variable-into-posixct). However, the original dataset just has 3 columns and I made more and I think I may work less process to find the hour range of the smallest people. How to simplifier the code and there are any suggests that can do the same result and easier way to understand for a beginner.

```
hr.range
[1] "05:00:00 - 04:59:59"
```

Also, my final expected result is a new column like this and reduce additional columns.

```
final.hr.range
    [1] "01:00:00 - 01:59:59"
    [2] "02:00:00 - 02:59:59"
    [3] "05:00:00 - 05:59:59"
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the time ranges between each of the elements in `df.test$time`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find the time ranges between each of the elements in df.test$time

Comment: do the results need to be grouped by "id" column? ... according to your final expected result you are just stating that one or more records are located in each of the three hours... you don't care how many records, and you don't care the ID of those records.  is that correct?

Comment: The time range may be the main concerns as I don't have any idea now.

Comment: The results need to be group by the hour to find how many rows are there and I showed what I can do. Ideally, the group of the range of time can be related to the number of people. Sorry for any misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use `lubridate` package to get the hourly range for the data. The `floor_date` will provide you start hour of a time, `ceiling_date` minus 1 will provide you last second of that hour. Then use `interval` to create interval of representing that particular hour. I'm not sure if OP's intention to keep `date` part of `interval`, but I kept the `date` as part of interval. Finally, `group_by` will work perfectly on interval.

Hence, you can use it as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

**Option#1:** Range includes both `Date/Time`

```
df.test %>% mutate(final.hr.range = interval(floor_date( date.time, "hour"), 
                                ceiling_date( date.time, "hour") - 1))

#   id     time           date.time                                   final.hr.range
# 1  1 01:30:00 2018-05-19 01:30:00 2018-05-19 01:00:00 BST--2018-05-19 01:59:59 BST
# 2  2 02:05:00 2018-05-19 02:05:00 2018-05-19 02:00:00 BST--2018-05-19 02:59:59 BST
# 3  2 02:40:01 2018-05-19 02:40:01 2018-05-19 02:00:00 BST--2018-05-19 02:59:59 BST
# 4  1 01:44:01 2018-05-19 01:44:01 2018-05-19 01:00:00 BST--2018-05-19 01:59:59 BST
# 5  1 01:33:01 2018-05-19 01:33:01 2018-05-19 01:00:00 BST--2018-05-19 01:59:59 BST
# 6  1 05:00:01 2018-05-19 05:00:01 2018-05-19 05:00:00 BST--2018-05-19 05:59:59 BST
```

**Option#2:** Range in `%H:%M:%S` format

```
df.test %>% mutate(final.hr.range = 
                paste(format(floor_date( date.time, "hour"), "%H:%M:%S"),
                      format(floor_date( date.time, "hour") + 3599, "%H:%M:%S"), 
                      sep = " - "))


#   id     time           date.time      final.hr.range
# 1  1 01:30:00 2018-05-19 01:30:00 01:00:00 - 01:59:59
# 2  2 02:05:00 2018-05-19 02:05:00 02:00:00 - 02:59:59
# 3  2 02:40:01 2018-05-19 02:40:01 02:00:00 - 02:59:59
# 4  1 01:44:01 2018-05-19 01:44:01 01:00:00 - 01:59:59
# 5  1 01:33:01 2018-05-19 01:33:01 01:00:00 - 01:59:59
# 6  1 05:00:01 2018-05-19 05:00:01 05:00:00 - 05:59:59
```

**Data:** Taken from OP

```
#sample data
df.test <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,1,1,1), 
  time=c("01:30:00","02:05:00","02:40:01","01:44:01","01:33:01","05:00:01"))

df.test $date.time <- as.POSIXct(df.test $time,format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Yes, my expected result is option 2 but the option 1 also helps me to know the processing how it runs. It a first time to use this lubridate library.

Comment: I face some problem. This my new dataset : #sample data
df.test <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,2,1,1,1,2),time=c("01:30:00","02:05:00","02:40:01","01:44:01","01:33:01","05:00:01","00:00:00")) . I add "00:00:00". When I run the code. the 2018-05-19 00:00:00 will be group to 00:00:00-23:59:59

Comment: @hahakwok I have updated my answer. It should work now. Loop for `option#2` changes.

Comment: oh, thank you. I notice that the problem of -1 then it converts to 23:59:59.

Comment: @hahakwok My pleasure. You can delete the chat texts which wont add value for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `lubridate` package:

```
hr_text <- function(t) {
  h <- hour(hms(t))
  paste(h, ":00:00 - ", h, ":59:59", sep="")
}
df.test$final.hr.range <- sapply(df.test$time, hr_text)

> df.test$final.hr.range
[1] "1:00:00 - 1:59:59" "2:00:00 - 2:59:59" "2:00:00 - 2:59:59" "1:00:00 - 1:59:59"
[5] "1:00:00 - 1:59:59" "5:00:00 - 5:59:59"
```